React Native make children fill in empty space evenly
I have a container that has a scrollview component nested inside that is also a container. Inside the scrollview container, I am looping through data and then trying to make the children be 2 items per row and also fill in any remaining empty space automatically, however, it will only fill up half the parent container.

I would like the 6 boxes shown in the image to evenly distribute the height and fill in the remaining space in the container.
// React Native Element

  return (
    <SafeAreaView style={[{ flex: 1 }]}>
      <ScrollView
        contentContainerStyle={surveyScreenStyles().cardsContainer}
      >
        <View
          style={[surveyScreenStyles().cardsContainer]}
        >
          {surveyData?.surveys?.map((surveyDetails, i) => (
            <Card
              key={`suvey-card-${i}`}
              mode='elevated'
              style={[surveyScreenStyles().cards]}
            >
              <Card.Title
                title={surveyDetails.name}
                titleVariant='titleLarge'
                subtitle={surveyDetails.summary}
                subtitleNumberOfLines={2}
              />
            </Card>
          ))}
        </View>
      </ScrollView>
    </SafeAreaView>
  );
}

// css file
{
    cardsContainer: {
      backgroundColor: "#FFFFFF",
      justifyContent: 'space-evenly',
      flex: 1,
      flexWrap: 'wrap',
      flexDirection: 'row',
      padding: 5,
      gap: 10
    },
    cards: {
      backgroundColor: "#FFFFFF",
      borderRadius: 10,
      flexBasis: '45%',
      justifyContent: 'center',
      padding: 10,
    }
}


If you use a flatlist, you can use the numColumns prop and the columnWrapperStyle prop to get 2 columns with your desired spacing styles. Then to get the items to take up the remaining height you can use the onLayout prop to get the height and then divide by 3, since there are 2 items per row:
import {
  View,
  StyleSheet,
  ScrollView,
  SafeAreaView,
  FlatList,
  Image,
} from 'react-native';
import { Text, Card } from 'react-native-paper';
import { useState } from 'react';
import ResizeableView from './ResizeableView';
import useData from '../hooks/useData';

const numColumns = 2;
const gap = 10;

export default function AssetExample() {
  const [surveyData] = useData();
  const [flatlistHeight, setFlatlistHeight] = useState(0);
  return (
    <SafeAreaView style={{ flex: 1 }}>
      {/* draggable component to demonstrate responsiveness */}
      <ResizeableView />
      <FlatList
        style={{ flex: 1 }}
        data={surveyData?.surveys}
        contentContainerStyle={styles.cardsContainer}
        renderItem={({ item: surveyDetails, index: i }) => {
          const height = flatlistHeight / (6 / numColumns) - gap
          return (
            <Card
              mode="elevated"
              style={[
                styles.cards,
                { height },
              ]}>
              <Card.Content>
                <Card.Title
                  title={surveyDetails.name}
                  titleVariant="titleLarge"
                  subtitle={surveyDetails.summary}
                  subtitleNumberOfLines={2}
                />
                <Image
                  source={{ uri: surveyDetails.thumbnail }}
                  style={{ width: height*.5,height:height*.5, alignSelf:'center' }}
                />
              </Card.Content>
            </Card>
          );
        }}
        keyExtractor={(item, i) => `suvey-card-${i}`}
        onLayout={({ nativeEvent }) =>
          setFlatlistHeight(nativeEvent.layout.height)
        }
        numColumns={numColumns}
        columnWrapperStyle={{ justifyContent: 'space-evenly' }}
        pagingEnabled
      />
    </SafeAreaView>
  );
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  cardsContainer: {
    flexGrow: 1,
    padding: 5,
    gap,
  },
  cards: {
    backgroundColor: '#FFFFFF',
    borderRadius: 10,
    flexBasis: '45%',
    justifyContent: 'center',
    // borderWidth: 1,
  },
});

demo

Great answer and demo! Nice work!

It looks like the flexWrap might be what is messing this up. I think because of the scroll view that doesn't work quite how it should.
Here is a solution that doesn't look as clean as yours but has the desired result:
    <ScrollView
      contentContainerStyle={{
        flex: 1,
        flexDirection: 'column',
        padding: 5,
        gap: 10,
      }}
    >
      <View style={{ flex: 1, flexDirection: 'row', gap: 10 }}>
        <View
          style={{
            backgroundColor: '#FFFFFF',
            borderRadius: 10,
            justifyContent: 'center',
            padding: 10,
            flex: 1,
          }}
        ></View>
        <View
          style={{
            backgroundColor: '#FFFFFF',
            borderRadius: 10,
            justifyContent: 'center',
            padding: 10,
            flex: 1,
          }}
        ></View>
      </View>
      <View style={{ flex: 1, flexDirection: 'row', gap: 10 }}>
        <View
          style={{
            backgroundColor: '#FFFFFF',
            borderRadius: 10,
            justifyContent: 'center',
            padding: 10,
            flex: 1,
          }}
        ></View>
        <View
          style={{
            backgroundColor: '#FFFFFF',
            borderRadius: 10,
            justifyContent: 'center',
            padding: 10,
            flex: 1,
          }}
        ></View>
      </View>
      <View style={{ flex: 1, flexDirection: 'row', gap: 10 }}>
        <View
          style={{
            backgroundColor: '#FFFFFF',
            borderRadius: 10,
            justifyContent: 'center',
            padding: 10,
            flex: 1,
          }}
        ></View>
        <View
          style={{
            backgroundColor: '#FFFFFF',
            borderRadius: 10,
            justifyContent: 'center',
            padding: 10,
            flex: 1,
          }}
        ></View>
      </View>
    </ScrollView>


Is scrollview necessary in react native? From what I read providing integration with touch locking "responder" system. Do you know what touch locking responder system is

Scrollview is important if you want your content to be scrollable. Which in this case you might not but most the time when you are creating a list like this you want to account for items overflowing the page view area. I am not sure what you are asking about locking the touch responder system. The native layer handles most of your gesture recognition if that is what you are asking about.

@phantomSpooks answer is what I would if this was my project because FlatList will also handle virtualization. So if you could potentially have a lot of items in your list the app will be more performant.
